mi Archivo Exit.php no funciona
Tengo mi archivo exit.php (que es para destruir mi sesión y dirigirlo a otra página posteriormente) en una carpeta llamada includes, y un archivo llamado index.php en donde se encuentra mi login para iniciar sesión. Este archivo index.php está afuera de todo, no está en alguna carpeta ni nada.
Lo único que quiero es destruir la sesión con el archivo exit.php pero me manda error 404 y no he podido ver el error.
exit.php
<?php
    session_start(); // Inicia la sesión o continúa la existente
    session_unset(); // Libera todas las variables de sesión
    session_destroy(); // Destruye la sesión
    
    // Redirige a la página de inicio (index.php) que está en el directorio raíz
    header("Location: ../index.php"); // Ajusta la ruta relativa según la estructura de tu proyecto
    exit(); // Asegúrate de detener la ejecución del script

?>

index.php
<?php
session_start();

// Verifica si ya se ha iniciado sesión
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    // Si ya ha iniciado sesión, redirige al usuario a la página del menú
    header("Location: vista/menu.php");
    exit; // Es importante salir del script después de redirigir
}

// El resto del código de la página de inicio de sesión continúa aquí
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="library/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Incluye la biblioteca SweetAlert2 -->
    <script src="library/sweetalert2@10.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="login">


    <div class="container contelogin">
        <div class="box form-box boxlogin">



            <?php
            include("database/conexion.php");

            // Aqui comprueba el formulario de acceso//

            if (isset($_POST['btnacceso'])) {
                $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $password_md5 = md5($password);

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password";
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password_md5, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();

                $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if ($row) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['usuario'];
                    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
                    $_SESSION['apellidos'] = $row['apellidos'];
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
                    $_SESSION['trozo'] = $row['trozo'];
                } else {
                    echo "<script>
            Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'Usuario/Contraseña Incorrecta'
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        window.location.href = 'index.php';
                    }
                });
            </script>";
                    exit; // ¡Importante! Asegúrate de salir del script para evitar que el código continúe ejecutándose.
                }

                if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
                    header("Location: vista/menu.php");
                    exit;
                } // ¡Importante! Asegúrate de salir del script después de redirigir para evitar que el código continúe ejecutándose.


            } else {



            ?>

                <!-- formulario de inicio -->

                <img src="img/logoSemar.png" class="imgLogoSemar"></img>

                <form action="" method="post">

                    <div class="field input">
                        <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
                        <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" require>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field input">
                        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" require>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="submit" class="btnLogin" name="btnacceso" id="btnacceso" value="Acceder" required>
                    </div>

                </form>
        </div>
    <?php  }
    ?>
    </div>


    <script src="library/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>




</body>

</html>


¿Dónde incluyes exit.php? ¿Cómo se relacionan las dos páginas? También, ¿a qué te refieres cuando dices "mi archivo exit.php no funciona? ¿Cómo no funciona? Parece que dices que recibes un error 404, pero ¿te destruye la sesión correctamente? Deberías editar la pregunta para añadir más detalles.

Tan mal no está... como te dice Alvaro, no incluyes a "exit,php" por ningún lado. Ojo no confundas exit; con tu archivo exit.php
